# Assistance in showing the limit of $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x \sin^{2}y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I've been asked to decide if the following limit exists and provide justification.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x \sin^{2}y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

One idea that I had and it seems to be giving me the closest chance of success was to do the following:

$$\frac{x \sin^{2}y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}  \leq x\ \frac{\sin\ y}{y} \ \frac{\sin\ y}{y}$$

Now from single variable calculus we know $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin\ y}{y} = 1$ and clearly $\lim_{x \to 0} x = 0$. My problem though is trying to squeeze it from below. It is not necessarily the case that the original function is always positive because of that pesky single $x$ value in the numerator.

A hint we were given was to remember the behaviour of $|\sin\ y|$ that would control the function. Which I feel would be the idea that $|\sin\ y| \leq 1$. Using that idea I would still end up in a situation where I'm left with

$$\frac{x \sin^{2}y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}  \leq \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$$

and I'm not sure how I can control that to my benefit.

Could I get some sort of guiding hint or tip on how to approach this if I'm not using the right ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following inequality
$$
\biggl|\frac{x\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}\biggr|\le \frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$
and substituting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$, you can get to the expected result.

Comment: So it was the other inequality about $\sin$, namely $|\sin\ x| \leq |x|$. I actually had a question with respect to how you used the absolute value bars? So in situations like this the reason behind taking the absolute value bars is that the value that bounds my function will be true for the upper and lower bound so as such it serves as a value to squeeze my function between? ....Also thank you

Comment: Your observation is correct. Showing that the magnitude of a function tends to zero is just equivalent to showing that the function itself tends to zero. We have better manipulations with absolute values.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Define $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$
We go to show that $\left|\frac{x\sin^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-0\right|<\varepsilon$
whenever $(x,y)\in B((0,0),\delta)\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$ Let $(x,y)\in B((0,0),\delta))\setminus\{(0,0)\}$
be arbitrary, i.e, $0<x^{2}+y^{2}<\delta^{2}$. Choose $r>0$ and
$\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.
Note that $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\delta$. Since $|\sin y|\leq|y|$,
we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\frac{x\sin^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-0\right| & \leq & \left|\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\\
 & = & \left|\frac{r^{3}\cos \theta\sin^{2}\theta}{r^{2}}\right|\\
 & \leq & r\\
 & < & \delta\\
 & = & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x\sin^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0.$

Comment: I think you missed a $\cos\ \theta$ in one line of the final solution

Comment: Typo. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that, $$\left|\dfrac{x\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \dfrac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}.$$ We have that $(|x|-y)^2\geq 0$, so, $x^2-2|x|y+y^2\geq 0$, that is, $x^2+y^2\geq 2|x|y$. Hence, $$\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\leq \dfrac{1}{2|x|y}.$$ Thus, $$\left|\dfrac{x\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \dfrac{y}{2}.$$

Comment: slick....what made you take the idea $(|x| - y)^{2} \geq 0$?

Comment: It's a strategy to solve this kind of limits. I learned it at college. It's very helpful.